# Can someone explain the difference between these two Youtube URLs?

Tags: youtube

Im building a site which opens Youtube videos onsite using Shadowbox.

I have found out that linking to a video this way ...

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDZFf0pm0SE
```

..doesn't work (Shadowbox opens, video doesnt play).  But linking this way...

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/wDZFf0pm0SE
```

.. does.

Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The /v/ link is a direct link to the video, which is used for embedding it. You use it like this:

`<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/wDZFf0pm0SE&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="800" height="600"></embed>`

However, due to licensing restrictions some videos will fail to play in the /v/ format.
The `&autoplay=1` part just tells it to start the video on page-load. (Remove it to not do that).
The normal link is used to watch the video from Youtube itself.

Hope this helps.